# How can I save cell value in datagridview rows from a loop and pass it to another loop for each row?

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I have datagridview with DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn i want to update the database if checkbox checked update the test_status to 5 , if check box not checked keep the test_status = 4 . the column name initial result.

I used the following code when click SAVE button:

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                 int test_status = 4;



     for (int i = 0; i < dgvResult.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                      foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvResult.Rows)
                    {
                      bool status = (bool)row.Cells[8].FormattedValue;
                        if (status)
                        {
                            test_status = 5;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            test_status = 4;
                        }
                    }
                        result.UPDATE_LABORDERS_RESULTS(Convert.ToInt32(txtOrder.Text),txtExamUser.Text,
                                                  DateTime.Parse(DateTimeExamined.Value.ToString()),
                                                  Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value),
                                                  dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString(),
                                                  dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(),
                                                  Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString()),
                                                  Convert.ToInt32(txtPno.Text),
                                                  Convert.ToInt32(txtcustid.Text),
                                                  dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
                                                  Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString()),
                                                  Convert.ToInt32(txtUpdateCount.Text),test_status);


                    }

                    MessageBox.Show("Result Saved Successfully ", "Entering Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                }
    }
```

[image]

what is the wrong with my code , what i need to update ?

UPDATE : 
I debug the code its taking the value of last row only not each row , when i checked the box for last row in datagridview its updated all rows in the database and keep test status = 5 for all rows.

how to pass test_status from first foreach  loop to second update_laborders_results?

Comment: test_status only has the value of the last row.  You have to grab that value for the row you are on in the update loop.

Comment: @LarsTech how i will do it can you post the code ?

Comment: Get rid of your for-each.  Move that code in your for-loop.

Comment: I see your updated code.  My comment still stands: get rid of the for-each.

Comment: @LarsTech i put the loop inside the main loop but still same taking last row value , what do you mean by get rid of for-each?

Comment: Literally, remove it.  Look what it does.  It loops through the rows, so the last row is the one that determines the value of test_status.  test_status needs to be determined based on the row you are on, the "i" variable.

Comment: @LarsTech can you help me how to do it i tried alot but its not working

Comment: Not sure where you are stuck.  Like I said, delete the for-each loop.  Change this line: `bool status = (bool)dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your database with test_status first for each row if checkbox checked to 5 then execute the other loop like this :

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
            for (int i = 0; i < dgvResult.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                         foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvResult.Rows)
                            {

                                bool status = (bool)row.Cells[8].FormattedValue;
                                if (status)
                                {
                                    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
                                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE table set test_status = 5 // where condition ", con);
                                    con.Open();
                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    con.Close();
                                }


                                result.UPDATE_LABORDERS_RESULTS(Convert.ToInt32(txtOrder.Text), txtExamUser.Text,
                                                      DateTime.Parse(DateTimeExamined.Value.ToString()),
                                                      Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value),
                                                      dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(),
                                                      dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString(),
                                                      Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString()),
                                                      Convert.ToInt32(txtPno.Text),
                                                      Convert.ToInt32(txtcustid.Text),
                                                      dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
                                                      Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString()), Convert.ToInt32(txtUpdateCount.Text));
```